# tmux with vim command output margins way off

Tags: vim, tmux

When I run commands such as !ls or !rspec in vim while using tmux the output of the screen seems to have a margin of about 50 and it jacks up all results, making it almost impossible to read.

If I strictly use vim and try the commands the output is just fine so it appears its an issue with tmux or a configuration option I need to set.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the term variable is wrong inside tmux. It should be either screen or screen-256color. You can check this with `echo $TERM`

Comment: so it was set to screen-256color...but for whatever reason I had to switch my iTerm to xterm and them back to xterm-256color and it worked.  Thanks a bunch it was driving me nuts.